# Python Rock, Paper, Scissors game bug?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created my first ever functional program but something's wrong. If I run the following code, considering every possible outcome, I get wrong results sometimes. For example, the user chooses rock, the program scissors, and the result is the program won, when it should not. I'm a beginner, so this might be a newbie mistake.

```
starter = True
while starter:
  import random
  user_input = input("Choose Rock, Paper or Scissors: ")
  choice = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
  choice_lower = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
  program_choice = random.choice(choice)

  while user_input not in choice or user_input in choice_lower:
    if user_input in choice or user_input in choice_lower:
        break
    else:
        user_input = input("Invalid input! Choose Rock, Paper or Scissors: ")
        continue

  if user_input == program_choice or user_input == program_choice.lower():
    print(f"You chose: {user_input}")
    print(f"It's a draw! The computer chose {program_choice} too!")
  elif user_input == "Rock" or user_input == "rock" and program_choice == "Paper":
    print(f"You chose: {user_input}\nThe program chose: {program_choice}\nThe program won!")
  elif user_input == "Paper" or user_input == "paper" and program_choice == "Rock":
    print(f"You chose: {user_input}\nThe program chose: {program_choice}\nYou won!")
  elif user_input == "Scissors" or user_input == "scissors" and program_choice == "Paper":
    print(f"You chose: {user_input}\nThe program chose: {program_choice}\nYou won!")
  elif user_input == "Rock" or user_input == "rock" and program_choice == "Scissors":
    print(f"You chose: {user_input}\nThe program chose: {program_choice}\nYou won!")
  elif user_input == "Paper" or user_input == "paper" and program_choice == "Scissors":
    print(f"You chose: {user_input}\nThe program chose: {program_choice}\nThe program won!")
  elif user_input == "Scissors" or user_input == "scissors" and program_choice == "Rock":
    print(f"You chose: {user_input}\nThe program chose: {program_choice}\nThe program won!")

  keep_going = input("Do you wanna play again? (Yes/No): ")
  answers = ["Yes", "yes", "No", "no"]
  while keep_going not in answers:
    keep_going = input("Invalid input! Do you wanna play again? (Yes/No): ")
    continue
  if keep_going == "Yes" or keep_going == "yes":
    continue
  else:
    starter = False
```

Comment: `and` is more precedent than `or`  (see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), so these `if`s need parentheses, eg `(user_input == "Rock" or user_input == "rock") and program_choice == "Paper"`

Comment: also it would be much cleaner if you did a case-insensitive comparison - you're already using the `lower` string method elsewhere, so use it here: `if user_input.lower() == "rock" and program_choice == "Paper"`

Comment: Another thought is this:    Encode Rock, Paper and Scissors as 0, 1, 2 respectively, so you would have usercode and programcode.   Looking at the difference between them mod 3 should tell you the outcome, win, tie, or lose.   The encoding could be done by a map like { "rock": 0, "paper":1, "scissors":2}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking every case in a separate `if/elif` case, it's easier (and less error prone) to check things systematically. For instance, consider the following version of a (one-round) "rock paper scissors" program as an alternative.

```
import random

choice =["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
lose = [(choice[i],choice[(i+1)%3]) for i in range(3)]
# equivalent: lose = [("rock","paper"),("paper","scissors"),("scissors","rock")]

program_choice = random.choice(choice)
# print(program_choice) # useful if you want to cheat

while True:
    user_input = input("Choose Rock, Paper or Scissors: ").lower()
    if user_input in choice:
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid Input!")

print(f"You chose: {user_input}\nThe program chose: {program_choice}")
if user_input==program_choice:
    print("It\'s a draw!")
elif (user_input,program_choice) in lose:
    print("The program won!")
else:
    print("You won!")
```